# Blazor SMPT Emails not coming when Published on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, email, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server side application that takes some inputs makes some calculations and sends them to the user via email.

The whole process works fine from the localhost development but when published to Azure no emails are coming through and the app crashes when Send Email function runs.

[image]

This function is on my Index page so i am not sure if this is due the wrong configuration, but again, on the local host it works.

Also, i am using MailKit and found this exception

[image]

Comment: Can you add some exception handling and logging? This is not much to go on.

Comment: _"the app crashes"_ Do you have any logs that may highlight what the actual error is?

Comment: Not sure on how to add exception handling. The error produced is the typical restart application error message.

Comment: That is the generic message Blazor will show you. There is more going on behind the scenes. [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core) is an easy way to start logging in Azure.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have found the following exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 81.4.153.226:587

Comment: Maybe the mail service you are using is blocking the IP address this request is coming from. I would contact their support if it is an option.